# ImageView in relativelayout overlapping with other widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-relativelayout

I am trying to build a custom view in Android that shows an image, and some text fields (non-editable).

I started by extending the `RelativeLayout` class for my custom view.

In the constructor of my custom view I created an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, and added them to the layout.

The `TextView` is loaded immediately, but the `ImageView` is loaded on a different thread and the bitmap is populated through a handler.

Once the bitmap is loaded, the `ImageView` is overlapping the `TextView`. The `TextView` is supposed to be on the "right-of" the `ImageView`, but this adjustment is not happening automatically.

I tried using `customView.invalidate()`, but that did not help.

This problem is not there when the same components are declared via XML.

Any help in resolving would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {
    private TextView productName;
    private ImageView productImage;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initHandler();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
        int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    initHandler();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initHandler();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initHandler();
}

private void initHandler() {
    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // implement logic to show content here
            productName.setText(currentProduct.getTitle());
            productImage.setImageBitmap(currentProduct.getImageBitmap());

            MyView.this.invalidate();
        }
    };      

    productImage = new ImageView(getContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    productImage.setLayoutParams(layout);

    //keep the textview to right of imageview
    productName = new TextView(getContext());
    layout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, productImage.getId());
    layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    productName.setLayoutParams(layout);        
    productName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    this.addView(productImage);
    this.addView(productName);

    //logic to load content on a new thread goes here
}
```

}

XML in which I included the custom view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.mycompany.MyView
    android:background="@android:color/black"           
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add an id to your View in xml

```
<com.mycompany.MyView

android:id="@+id/myView"

android:background="@android:color/black"           
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and in your java initilize it like

```
ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
```

try that